# how to auto increase the number of concurrent users in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I have a thread group with login request and try to doing concurrent users load for this request.
I have recorded login scenario for single user and replacing other users using parameterization.
For creating small no of users data in csv file is not an issue.But when trying to create 10k users is more difficult for csv file.
Is there any way to do this simple?
Means,simply change last value after user
For example : user1@gmail.com,user2@gmail.com, user3@gmail.com........so on..upto 10k users
If i want to test for 1000, 10k users without changing manually users data and increase as much as users simply define 100 (for 100 users)?
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function which you can use as a part of username like:

   ```
   user${__threadNum}@gmail.com
   ```

   This way first JMeter thread (virtual user) will resolve into `user1@gmail.com`, second thread into `user2@gmail.com`, etc.

   [image: JMeter threadnum]
2. You can also consider [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter), it generates an incremented value each time it's being called, the syntax is pretty much the same:

   ```
   user${__counter(,)}@gmail.com
   ```

   [image: JMeter Counter incrementing number]

Most probably option 1 is something you're looking for, but be aware of __counter() approach just in case. Also check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: How can I do same for the registration process